# Compare image size from Upload and upload_max_size

Tags: php, html

When i upload some images from  and get size of image with  `$ size = $_FILES["name of input"]["size"]` it returns "57379" (for example). Ok then i get upload max size with `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` return here is 64M, and i want to compare these two values like this:

```
if ($size > ini_get('upload_max_filesize') {...}
```

how to do it ? the image is in kilobytes i think the other is megabytes (i'm not sure )

Comment: write a simple converter function!?

Comment: i tried some converter function without success

Comment: and btw: if the size of the uploaded file would be greater than upload_max_filesize it wouldn't upload anyway.

Comment: then include that function here and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to catch error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [size of the $_FILES](http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.post-method.php) array is in bytes and the `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` get megabytes (64M).
Don't forget to check the `ini_get('post_max_size');`
If the size of the file is bigger than `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` the `$_FILES` array get content in the `error` field

```
$php_size = substr(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), 0, -1) * 1048576;

if ($size > $php_size) {...}
```

Comment: Okay, that's it ! Thank u !

Comment: About the `* 1048576` from the `64M` string, source from php.net : http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes

Answer (score 0):

```
$upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); //64MB
$size=$_FILES["name of input"]["size"]
```

64MB = 67108864 bytes

Now you can compare it

```
if ($size > $upload_max_size) {...}
```

Comment: without convert ?

Comment: u suggest to use this 67108864 but i dont't want to hardcode

Comment: Then we have to convert it (MB to Byte)
1MB = 1048576 Bytes so 64 MB = 67108864 Byte